# My blog doesn't display properly with Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am sure this is easy stuff for all the readers of this website but this kind of problem is difficult for me.

I have a website http://www.areacatracha.com that doesn't show up properly in Internet Explorer.  Other browser display it normally.

Can anyone help me?

Any suggestions about how to start fixing these kinds of cross-browser compatibility issues?

Answer (score 8):

After taking a quick peak at the link you provided I have the following recommendation:

Validate your HTML code using an html validator. One possibility is to use 
validator.w3.org.

Using the HTML Validator plugin for Firefox, I got 500+ errors on rendering your page. I'm fairly certain that one or more of these errors is responsible for the page failing to render in IE.

Once you've identified the errors through validation, then you can fix them. ;-)